# How to install Yii framework in an android devices?

Tags: php, android, yii

I am studying Yii framework in my android phone. I have an application called **AndroPHP**. It has a **LightHttpd, MySql and PHP**.

I can run CodeIgniter, Wordpress and Smarty in my phone but I don't have an idea how can I install a Yii framework. I searched in the Internet I can't find any correct solution.

I tried to install it using the **yiic webapp** in my android terminal emulator. And my error is

**sh: yiic: not found**

I have a YII framework extracted in **sdcard/www/YII/**

And I used the yiic in the framework folder.

To access the yiic I have this path:

**root@android:/storage/sdcard0/www/YII/framework#**

And to use the yiic I have this

**yiic webapp sdcard0/www/bid**

where **bid** is my folder under **www**

Any idea how can I install this framework? Or any android application that has a tutorial in installing Yii. Ok that's all thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use `./yiic webapp sdcard0/www/bid` you should use ./ since current directory is not included in path.

Comment: included the (.) dot before the forward slash?

Comment: can you please explain what is this and how are we suppose to run php and the frame work on android (I know it's linux based :D )?

Comment: @tinyByte -  I just download the app called AndroPHP. The others are Bitwebserver, Servers Ultimate, etc...

Comment: Ok I tried that but it says /yiic: can't execute: Permission denied

Comment: After performing the chmod 755 yiic. I run the yiic webapp. The response is 'Permission denied' :(

Comment: copy the file yiic to PC run chmod 755 yiic then copy back the file to phone. then try to execute it.